# How can linear types prevent such implementation of "duplicate"?

Tags: haskell, types, linear-types

I recently read [the post on Tweag.IO](https://www.tweag.io/posts/2017-03-13-linear-types.html) about Linear Types being an useful tool for expressing arguments used only(exactly) once. They present the following example:

```
dup :: a ⊸ (a,a)
dup x = (x,x)
```

Now, maybe I'm misunderstanding the idea, but why couldn't this be circumvented with:

```
dup' :: a ⊸ (a,a)
dup' x = (y,y)
  where
    y = x
```

The article specifically mentions *arguments*. Does that extend to all bindings in the function as well?

Comment: [Probably relevant](https://github.com/tweag/linear-types/releases/download/v1.0/hlt.pdf)

Comment: I feel this article gives almost no explanation of the underlying semantics - just examples of how one uses such a technology (to be fair, this is probably a good format for a blog post). You could view `x ⊸ y` as a synonym for `1 x -> y` which is a regular arrow, whose domain is `1 x` which says the variable `a :: 1 x` is used exactly once. By type inference, in your second example, `y` gets the inferred type `1 a` because `y = x` and `x :: 1 a`. This extends to all natural numbers and infinity, and is a nice generalization - the regular arrow `x -> y` can be read as `ω x -> y`.

Comment: See the proposal on the [trac](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/LinearTypes) for more details.

Comment: Oh, and the paper you've linked gives the semantics properly. See sec 3.1, fig. 2 - the typing rule corresponding to `let`. However, note that in that paper, the `let` construct always contains an explicit type signature on the `let`-bound variable. With the syntax of that paper, your 2nd program (and indeed, most Haskell programs!) are not even syntactically valid. But the point is that in the paper, the standard typing judgment `x : T` is generalized to `x :_{q} T` (that `q` should be a subscript). So a term is annotated with its type, and its multiplicity.

Comment: @user2407038 Those comments should be an answer ;)

Comment: Done - let me know if I can clarify anything (or make edits yourself if you would like) - I'm not exactly an expert on this subject.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I feel this article gives almost no explanation of the underlying semantics - just examples of how one uses such a technology. To be fair, this is probably a good format for a blog post.

You could view `x ⊸ y` as a synonym for `1 x -> y` which is a regular arrow, whose domain is `1 x` which says the variable `a :: 1 x` is used exactly once. By type inference, in your second example, `y` gets the inferred type `1 a` because `y = x` and `x :: 1 a`. This extends to all natural numbers and infinity. Furthermore, the regular arrow `x -> y` can be read as `ω x -> y`, where `ω` is infinity.

The [paper](https://github.com/tweag/linear-types/releases/download/v1.0/hlt.pdf) you've linked gives the semantics properly. See sec 3.1, fig. 2 - the typing rule corresponding to `let`. The standard typing judgment `x : T` is generalized to `x :_{q} T` (that q should be a subscript). In existing Haskell type semantics, a term is annotated with its type. In the proposed extension to the type system, a term is annotated with its type, and its multiplicity.

However, note that in that paper, the let construct always contains an explicit type signature on the let-bound variable. With the syntax of that paper, your 2nd program (and indeed, most Haskell programs!) are not even syntactically valid. But I claim (without proof) that it is not hard to see how to generalize such a type system to one with more reminiscent of the current Haskell type system. See the proposal on the GHC [trac](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/LinearTypes) for more details on how that might look.